# Stanford NLP core 4.0.0 no longer splitting verbs and pronouns in Spanish

Tags: windows, stanford-nlp

Very helpfully Stanford NLP core 3.9.2 used to split rolled together Spanish verbs and pronouns

[image]

This is the 4.0.0 output:

[image]

The previous version had more .tagger files.  These have not been included with the 4.0.0 distribution.

[image]

Is that the cause.  Will be they added back?

Comment: For future reference, if you would post text instead of images when possible, that would help other people cut & paste when replicating tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some documentation updates that still need to be made for Stanford CoreNLP 4.0.0.

A major change is that a new multi-word-token annotator has been added, that makes tokenization conform with the UD standard. So the new default Spanish pipeline should run `tokenize,ssplit,mwt,pos,depparse,ner`.  It may not be possible to run such a pipeline from  the server demo at this time, as some modifications will need to be made.  I can try to send you what such modifications would be soon.  We will try to make a new release in early summer to handle issues like this that we missed.

It won't split the word in your example unfortunately, but I think in many cases it will do the correct thing. The Spanish `mwt` model is just based off of a large dictionary of terms, and was tuned to optimize performance on the Spanish training data.

Comment: I pushed a change to the GitHub to fix this, and we'll update the online demo soon. It's a very small change to the javascript. If you want any help making a temporary update before Stanford CoreNLP 4.1.0 I can give advice.

Comment: Just to add an extra note, we expanded the MWT dictionary for Spanish, so your example would now be covered.