# POS Tag Set for Stanford NLP 4 Spanish

Tags: stanford-nlp

I asked a [question before about tokenization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540771/stanford-nlp-core-4-0-0-no-longer-splitting-verbs-and-pronouns-in-spanish) (getting the wrong end of the stick I believe.)  I see now that Stanford NLP 4 does the job of splitting Contractions & Clitic pronouns - very well - much better than the 3.x version.

However I'm still short on how to get the new 4.x version to return the bigger tag set mentioned in Question 6 on the FAQ https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/spanish-faq.html

E.g. To differentiate between nc0s000 & nc0p000  (Singular and Pural Nouns)

Is the .ud tagger going to be made available in future releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 4.2, only UD models are available.